# Linq generic parameter error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I know why this is happening but can somebody help me in the right direction of syntax?
Currently I have three tables joined by one to one optional relationship. And I joined them as left outer join. My query is....

```
var model = from t1 in db.Doctors
            join d in db.DoctorAddress on t1.DoctorId equals  d.DoctorId into listi
            join dc in db.DoctorCharges on t1.DoctorId equals dc.DoctorId into listj
            join da in db.DoctorAvailablities on t1.DoctorId equals da.DoctorId into listk
            from d in listi.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from dc in listj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from da in listk.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                Name = t1.Name,
                RoomNo = da.RoomNo,
                IPDCharge = dc.OPDCharge,
                Address = d.Address,
            };
```

My problem is that `OPDCharge` is of type `Decimal(not null)`

The error I get is:

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: What datatypes are `dc.OPDCharge` and `IPDCharge`? Also what is the datatype of the column in the database?

Comment: IPDCharge = dc.OPDCharge ?? 0;
Perhaps.

Comment: Column OPDCharge is of Decimal type.

Comment: @Jaan, are you sure? Does it allow nulls?

Comment: @gunr2171 No it does not allow nulls.

Comment: @Jaan, If the column does not allow nulls, then `OPDCharge` _must_ be a `double`, not a nullable (as you have stated). I suspect something wrong with your model. Refresh the model from the database source.

Answer (score 1):

I think an explicit cast to a nullable should do it:

```
IPDCharge = (decimal?)dc.OPDCharge
```

But the error message suggest that the type of `OPDCharge` is actually `double`, so maybe cast to `double?` instead?

Comment: @gunr2171 but `IPDCharge` is in an anonymous type an has the same type as the target.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept null as being 0 then try:

```
IPDCharge = dc.OPDCharge ?? 0;
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
IPDCharge = dc.OPDCharge.GetValueOrDefault(0)
```